# how to get value of hidden field in jquery checkbox.each loop?

Tags: jquery

I want to extract the value of the input type hidden value through a checkbox loop.
I extracted the value of the select option but the hidden value is undifiend.
I want to get that array in jquery function
please any suggestion.

```js
  <script id="reqList-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     {{#resultList}}
       {{#each rsToAdd}}
           <input type="hidden" name="doc_id" class="doc_id" value="{{doc_id}}">
           <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Chk" value="{{id}}">
           <select name="type" class="type">
  <option value="1_item" th:text="#{req.parentOf}"></option>
  <option value="2_item" th:text="#{req.blocks}"></option>
  <option value="3_item" th:text="#{req.dependsOn}"></option>
  <option value="4_item" th:text="#{req.relatedTo}"></option>
     </select>
       {{/each}}
     {{/resultList}}
  
  </script>
 
 checkbox.each(function(inex, item) {
    var selected = $(item).siblings("select").val();
    
    var commentid = $(item).siblings("input[name='doc_id']").val();   // undifined
    var commentid = $(item).siblings("input:hidden").val();    // undifined
    var commentid = $(item).find("[name=doc_id]").val();    // undifined
    
    relation_type.push({
   selected : selected
  });
 });
```

Comment: So that the snippet runs and we have a [MCVE] to see and debug, can you post the *rendered* DOM? (not the server template)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```js
var checkboxArr = [];
jQuery(".doc_id").each(function() {
  var id = jQuery(this).val();
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    checkboxArr[id] = id;
  }
});
console.log(checkboxArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" name="doc_id" class="doc_id" value="1" checked>
<input type="hidden" name="doc_id" class="doc_id" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="doc_id" class="doc_id" value="3" checked>
<input type="hidden" name="doc_id" class="doc_id" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="doc_id" class="doc_id" value="5">
<input type="hidden" name="doc_id" class="doc_id" value="6">
```

Comment: Updated can you check now

Comment: i want to find hidden value in checked checkbox each function. only checked data need hidden doc_id value. through $(item).siblings like get option value

Comment: Can you check now